# AUD Swap Reference Rate?

Tags: interest-rates, libor, benchmark

So I understand that BBSW is the reference rate used in AUD swap transactions since AUD LIBOR has been discontinued. If I want to build a curve out of the reference rates used to price AUD swaps, I can use the BBSW rates for maturities ranging from 1 day to 12 months, but what is the correct reference rate for maturities past 1 year? There is no BBSW rate for a 3 year maturity for example. What is the AUD BBSW analogue to a 5 year LIBOR or 10 year LIBOR rate?

Answer (score 2):

A 5 year AUD swap, for example, references a short term rate such as 3month BBSW.  There is no such thing as 5 year BBSW or 5 year AUD Libor.   The maturity of an interest rate swap is not the same thing as the maturity of its reference rate.

Is that what you were asking?